# Reading and use MIDI in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, midi

I'm using a simple USB-Midi Keyboard (Akai LPK25) and want to use it as a controller in a python script. 
I already learned that I can use pygame.midi for this but I do not really see how.

So what I want to do is something like:

```
if midikey23 == 1:
   x = 2
```

also it would be nice to use the velocity.

I don't have a good idea how to do this so I would be greatful for every answer!

Greetings,
RA

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Comment: Well, [`pygame.midi`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html) has pretty complete docs, with links to dozens of examples. It isn't going to give you a `midikey23`, but it will give you midi event that tells you that there's a key-down with key 23 and velocity 87. So, have you read those docs and looked at those samples and gotten stuck somewhere? Or are you just looking for someone to write your code for you?

Comment: I've read the docs and as already said, I don't really know how to do it.
`pygame.midi.Input(3).read`
`<bound method Input.read of <pygame.midi.Input object at 0x823c70>>`
`pygame.midi.Input(3).read`
`PortMidi call failed...`
  `PortMidi: `Invalid device ID'`
`type ENTER...`

That's how I would do it with the informations from the documentation. 

I don't want anyone to write my code, I just want to learn how I can write my code. ;)

Comment: In Python, you call a function by writing `()` after its name. Anyway, show your code that selects an input device and tries to read from it.